# Correct data to insert Contacts programmatically

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I've written the following methods to create contacts programmatically within my app

```
override fun addContactToPhone() {
    val ops = ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>()
    val rawContactId = ops.size

    try {
        ops.add(
            ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
                .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
                .build()
        )
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("Add", "could not find account_type null")
        return
    }

    addContactNameInfo(ops, rawContactId)
    addContactEmailInfo(ops, rawContactId)
    addContactInfo(ops, rawContactId)
}

private fun addContactInfo(
    ops: ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>,
    rawContactId: Int
) {
    ops.add(
        ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI).apply {
            withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId)
            withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, sPhoneNr)
            withValue(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK
            )
        }.build()
    )
}

private fun addContactEmailInfo(
    ops: ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>,
    rawContactId: Int
) {
    ops.add(
        ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI).apply {
            withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId)
            withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, sEmail)
        }.build()
    )
}

private fun addContactNameInfo(
    ops: ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>,
    rawContactId: Int
) {
    ops.add(
        ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI).apply {
            withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId)
            withValue(
                ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
            )
            // Name of the person
            withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME, sLastname)
            withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, sFirstname)
            withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.MIDDLE_NAME, sMiddleName)
        }.build()
    )
}
```

And I have few questions above correct data which I should use with Contacts provider:

1. How to get contactRawId variable? Is my idea correct?
2. In what format I should send the phone? If I have phone string like
   "+7(960)001-02-03" or "+34(960)001-02-03", what symbols I must cut from it?
3. Do I need to provide DISPLAY_NAME or it will be automatically formed
   from FAMILY_NAME, MIDDLE_NAME, GIVEN_NAME

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

1. do not pass `rawContactId` to your methods, instead put simply `0`, as in:
   `withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)`
   the "ValueBackReference" part means "use the ID you got from the first insert operation in this list of operations.
2. Under `Phone.NUMBER` you can put the phone in whatever format you want, the Contacts DB will store a strictly formatted (E164) phone number under `Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER` automatically
3. I think that's fine, you should usually submit either `DISPLAY_NAME` or the name parts